# J Programming Beginners Loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, j, tacit-programming

Could someone kindly explain the control structure in J (specifically For and While loops)?
Let's say I have a=:1 and b=:10, and I want to add '1' to 'a' using For/While loops till a < b.

So, usually it would be something like (in other languages)

```
for i= 1 to b   
a=a+1    
next i
```

or

```
while a<=b    
a=a+1    
end
```

Help please. I know it's simple, but I can't figure out how to do this in loops.

Also, I read up on something called "explicits". For example:

```
foo=: 3 : 0
if. 1 do. wdinfo 'success' end.
)
```

What would the 3 and 0 denote?

Comment: Well, that's a lot of questions for one post. Have you read ["Loopless code"](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_i_verbs_have_r.htm#_Toc191734331) from "J for C programmers"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Control structures](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/ctrl.htm) must be used within an [explicit definition](http://www.jsoftware.com/docs/help701/dictionary/d310n.htm).
The explicit definition link will explain what the "3" and "0" signify, but note that the following are equivalent.

```
myfunction=: 3 : 0
  NB. define function/verb here
) 

myfunction=: verb define
  NB. define function/verb here
)
```

Here is an example of defining an explicit function/verb containing a for loop:

```
for_eg=: verb define
 a=. 3
 b=. 8
 for. i.b do.
   a=. a + 1
 end. 
 a
)
```

Here is an example of using that verb:

```
for_eg ''
11
```

The Jwiki contains a [wiki page](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Guides/Defining%20Verbs) describing how to define a verb. Note the references at the bottom for more info.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply on this. Been busy. Many thanks Tikkanz. Your answer is apt, really helped me understand what I needed to. Special mention: The links you provided were really helpful.